# php subtract variable from Array

Tags: php, arrays, subtraction

I am defining the subtraction variable like so:

```
    $query = "
    SELECT * FROM around WHERE `long` != '' ORDER BY id DESC"; 
    $result = mysql_query( $query );

    $select_maxlong = mysql_query("SELECT long FROM around WHERE
    `id`='$max_id'");
    $row3 = mysql_fetch_row($select_maxlong);
    $max_long = $row3[0];
```

Then I need to subtract $max_long from the array value below:

```
   while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result ) ) {

   echo $row['long'];}
```

I have tried:

```
   foreach($row as $row) {
   $car = $max_long;
   echo "u";
   echo $car - $row['long'] ; }
```

But the output is not correct.

If there are 10 numbers in an array, $row['long'], I want to subtract $max_long from each of them, and echo the result.

Comment: And what is the output + what output do you expect?

Comment: It gives me multiple outputs. I just want one number.

Comment: one number of WHAT? You're fetching multiple rows of data, and subtracting a value from each of those rows. you'd have to explain what this "one number" should be, because right now your code is working perfectly well as-written.

Comment: `foreach($row as $row)` Whoa!

Comment: what do you mean Whoa? u_mulder

Comment: It is not working, it shoots out multiple variables.

Comment: How do you think if initially your `$row` is an array and you're doing `foreach`, then on first iteration `$row` will become a first item of `$row`. And what's next?

Comment: If there are 10 numbers in an array, $row['long'], I want to subtract $max_long from each of them, and echo the result.

Comment: Maybe you start to optimise your query? Don't collect al rows, but only the rows where you want the information from.....

Comment: I need to calculate this for all of them: If there are 10 numbers in an array, $row['long'], I want to subtract $max_long from each of them, and echo the result.

Comment: Just change the query to retrieve a scalar value: `SELECT SUM(long) FROM  table WHERE 1` and substract with that

Comment: There is **no more support** for `mysql_*` functions, they are [**officially deprecated**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), **no longer maintained** and will be [**removed**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php#warning) in the future. You should update your code with [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) to ensure the functionality of your project in the future.

Comment: DarkBee, need it in the format I posted, so it can be put into JSON.

Comment: Are we really even helping anyone on stackoverflow? It seems to me that many of the people posting questions on here have a fundamental lack of understanding of software design and engineering. I'm not saying that's the case here (the use of mysql_* functions leads me to believe that to be the case), but aren't we just enabling people to continue building poorly designed applications?

Comment: Gnarly, my desires are simple. Your philosophical thoughts are not helping, if that is what you are wondering.

Comment: @AdreamcathcerAdreamcatcher You'll get over it.

Comment: gnarly I'm just telling you I don't care about anything you think, unless you are solving my problem.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fd0668/5

Comment: The answer below by maci is a step in the right direction, but it is only calculating once.

Comment: I have added to the question, above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should work for you

```
$select_maxlong = mysql_query("SELECT long FROM around WHERE `id`='$max_id'");
$row3 = mysql_fetch_row($select_maxlong);
$max_long = $row3[0];

$myarray=array();
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result ) ) {
   $myarray[]=$row['long'];
}

function showvalue($element, $key) {
  echo $max_long-$element;
}

array_walk($myarray,'showvalue');
```

But this way, you are substracting the element from $max_long, and not otherwise as you said (that's what your code seems to try). If you want to really substract $max_long from each element of the array and output the result, just invert the variable order on the echo line. Hope this helps.

Comment: Can the output be placed inside ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result ) ) { } I am trying to use JSON.

Comment: The calculation worked here, but it only calculates it once. If there are 100 posts, I need it to run 100 times.

Comment: Then you don't need to create a new array. Just do `echo $max_long-$row['long']; ` inside the while() {...} block

Comment: I don't think I understand... this function will echo one result per element of the original array. If there are 100, it will output 100 values.

Comment: The result is 0 when I do that.

Comment: It does result all 100 when I post exactly what you have above. But, when I put array_walk($myarray,'showvalue'); it stops scripting after it prints results. Need to have the echo inside the while...but it comes out as 0 when I do echo $max_long-$row['long'];

Comment: You should post more complete code If you need further help. There is a gap which I can only guess (where is $result defined?). Besides, I don't know what data is present in your original arrays. The result could be 0.

Comment: Result is never 0. $query = "
  SELECT *
  FROM around WHERE `long` != '' 
  ORDER BY id DESC";
$result = mysql_query( $query );

Comment: Does your original code here `while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result ) ) { echo $row['long'];}` display the _n_ different values of the array? If it does, it wil also display `$max_long-$row['long']` if changed the way I told you. If it does not, the reason is somewhere else.

Comment: Original code does display the values of the array. But, it does not display the subtraction. It comes up as 0. Even if I echo $max_long right before subtracting. Why could this be?

Comment: The only reason I can think of is that the value of $max_long is not what you expect to be.